# How do I fix this error in Magento 1.9.2.0?

Tags: php, magento, fatal-error

I have an error in `Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php` **line 389** it only happens on the product view page.

here's what Abstract.php line 389 has:

```
    public function getSource()
{
    if (empty($this->_source)) {
        if (!$this->getSourceModel()) {
            $this->setSourceModel($this->_getDefaultSourceModel());
        }
        $source = Mage::getModel($this->getSourceModel());
        if (!$source) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Eav',
                Mage::helper('eav')->__('Source model "%s" not found for attribute "%s"',$this->getSourceModel(), $this->getAttributeCode())
            );
        }
// 389-->        $this->_source = $source->setAttribute($this);
    }
    return $this->_source;
}
```

The error outputs only this: Fatal error:  **Call to undefined method** `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno::setAttribute()` in `/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php` on **line 389**.

A while back I found a piece of code that I could use by adding it right above the line in Magento core file that would print out more about the error but I can't find it. Anyway how would I go about tracking this thing down?

Comment: You could include a hint about the error in your question title (like "Model", "Entity" ... ; I do not know magento).

Comment: I would guess that this is down to a third party module calling setAttribute on a source model that it's using incorrectly.  I would suggest disabling local/community modules initally

Comment: @user2533583 Have you deleted any attribute from attribute set?

Comment: What's `$this` in your case?

Comment: No I haven'tr deleted any attributes. Not sure what you mean about $this, I was just pointing out line 389. I think a new module has added something but I'm not sure been turning off and checking but it might be added to the database.